# calculate numbers on end and merge to one line

Tags: sed, awk, python, perl

So in a file i have lines like these:

```
thisdata:thisother:1337
thisdata:thisother:1800
thisdata:thisother:1500
thisdata:thisother:46984
```

I would like to output:

```
thisdata:thisother:51621
```

for all lines, differenciating amount of lines per dataset with alternating numbers on the end that I'd like to merge.

More examples:

```
somedata:somedata:1339

othrsome:othersomemore:14949
othrsome:othersomemore:14949

uruie:eiiwi:1399
uruie:eiiwi:1399
uruie:eiiwi:1399
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` and an associative array keyed on the first two columns:

```
awk -F : '{ sum[$1 FS $2] += $3; }; END { OFS=FS; for (key in sum) print key, sum[key]; }' file
```

Comment: Brilliant again!